# Find id number in url using javascript

Tags: javascript

Currently I am scraping the end of an url using javascript like so:

```
var url = document.URL;
var sale = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
if(sale != "")
```

So if there is this /sales/1234 it would pick it up, trouble is it still works for something else like sales/anotherword/1234, is there an easy way to adjust this to only pick up the number after "/sales/"?

Comment: Updated : http://stackoverflow.com/a/22155056/1636522.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using regular expressions:

```
var url = document.URL;
var sale = null;

var matches = url.match(/\/sales\/(\d+)/);

if(matches.length && matches[1]){
   sale = matches[1];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do a bit more validating:

1. Make sure there is no `/` after the one after `sales`.
2. Make sure that the value you get is a number.

Something like this could work:

```
var url = document.URL;
var sale = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('/sales/') + 1);
if(sale.indexOf('/') < 0 && !isNaN(sale)) {
    //Handle the sale
}
else {
    //sale either contains a / or is not a number
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also do this :

```
var sale = parseInt(url.split('/sales/')[1], 10);
if (!isNaN(sale)) {
    // do something
}
```

`parseInt()` returns `NaN` (Not A Number) in case of failure.

---

Here is a function :

```
function toSaleId(url) {
    var id = parseInt(url.split('/sales/')[1], 10);
    if (!isNaN(id)) return id; 
}
```

Usage examples :

```
var sale = toSaleId('/sale/1234'); // 1234
var sale = toSaleId('/sale/1234/anotherworld'); // 1234
var sale = toSaleId('/sale/anotherworld/1234'); // undefined
```